# AJAX Firing OnUnload Twice

Tags: c#, ajax

All, thanks in advance.

I'm using the ASP.NET AJAX Control Toolkit to create 2 CascadingDropDowns. The problem is the base OnUnload is firing twice when I load the page. Any idea how to stop this? See code snippets below.

**Update:** I've determined a workaround but if anyone knows of a way to suppress, I would be interested to hear!

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" 
  CodeFile="dataentry.aspx.cs" 
  Inherits="dataentry" 
  EnableEventValidation="false" %>

<ajaxToolkit:ToolkitScriptManager EnablePartialRendering="true" 
  runat="server" 
  ID="ScriptManager1" />

<asp:DropDownList ID="drpDate" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList>
<ajaxToolkit:CascadingDropDown ID="CascadingDropDown1" runat="server" 
  TargetControlID="drpDate" 
  Category="Date" 
  PromptText="Please select a date" 
  ServicePath="SchedulerService.asmx" 
  ServiceMethod="GetSchedulerDates" 
  UseContextKey="true" />

<asp:DropDownList ID="drpTime" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList>
<ajaxToolkit:CascadingDropDown ID="CascadingDropDown2" runat="server" 
  TargetControlID="drpTime" 
  ParentControlID="drpDate" 
  PromptText="Please select a time" 
  ServiceMethod="GetSchedulerTimesForDate" 
  ServicePath="SchedulerService.asmx" 
  Category="Time" 
  UseContextKey="true" />
```

Comment: I've been simulating in IE8 and then on the iPad (Safari).

Comment: I too am seeing onunload firing twice when using ToolkitScriptManager.  In Firefox (3.6.13) and IE 8, this only happens when the browser cache is empty.  In Chrome (8.0.552.237), it happens regardless of browser's cache.  When I switch to ScriptManager, no such problem.

Comment: @RyanW If you put that as an answer I'll give it an upvote as it worked for me!!